# Javascript `replace` Replacement Fallback

Tags: javascript, regex

Take the following example:

```js
var tag_oh_so_alone_ = '[FieldName]',
    tag_with_default = '[FieldName:The default value]',
    the_regex = /\[([a-z]+)(\:([^\]]+))?\]/i;

console.log(
    "Results:\n",
    tag_oh_so_alone_.replace(the_regex,"1: $1\n 2: $2\n 3: $3\n"),
    tag_with_default.replace(the_regex,"1: $1\n 2: $2\n 3: $3\n")
);
```

The console reads:

```
Results:
 1: FieldName
 2: 
 3: 
 1: FieldName
 2: :The default value
 3: The default value
```

What I'd like to do is, within the replacement declaration (in other words, the place where we include "$1" etc), specify basically: if `$3` is populated use `$3`, otherwise use `$1`.

The expected output would be the following:

> `tag_oh_so_alone_` => `FieldName`
>
> `tag_with_default` => `The default value`

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @thefourtheye - added. Essentially: (1) if data for `FieldName` exists (not covered here) use it, otherwise... (2) if a default exists use it, otherwise... (3) display the field name (without brackets).

Comment: It was my answer only. But your question is not very clear. So please check [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) of the documentation. This will help you.

Comment: Do you want to add it back to I can accept it?

Comment: No, its fine. Please let me know if that section of the documentation helps :)

Comment: It's helpful. Your original answer was more concise, though. It could have benefited from that "source link".

Comment: Well, I have undeleted my answer. Does it help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [pass a function as the replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) to the `String.replace`, like this

```
function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3) {
    if (p3) {
        return "1: " + p1 + "\n 2: " + p2 + "\n 3: " + p3 + "\n"
    } else {
        return "1: " + p1 + "\n 2: " + p1 + "\n 3: " + p1 + "\n"
    }
}

console.log(
    "Results:\n",
    tag_oh_so_alone_.replace(the_regex, replacer),
    tag_with_default.replace(the_regex, replacer)
);
```

with that, the output becomes,

```
Results:
 1: FieldName
 2: FieldName
 3: FieldName
 1: FieldName
 2: :The default value
 3: The default value
```

Here, `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are the actual matched groups. If `p3` is not populated/matched, then it will be `undefined`. You can customize the return value of the function, as you like in the `replacer` function.